# How to update tick position depending on whether it's negative/positive in d3js v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/8262437e043adc8867ce1d4a4cdd63d6) **(SOLVED)** bar chart where I would like to update the position of the y-ticks when the data is updated from positive to negative and vice versa.

I've tried to update the .tick class in the update function and the filter

```
.filter(function(d, i) { return data[i]['value' + TEAM] < 0; });
```

and other various methods to update the position but I get nothing back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, the problem was that the ticks that got adjusted in the filter function

```
.filter(function(d, i) { return data[i]['value' + TEAM] < 0; });
```

only adjusted the ticks that were less than 0, my updated filter

```
.filter(function(d, i){ if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] > 0)
{return true;}else if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] < 0){return true;}});
```

makes sure that all ticks gets included.

After that i just update the appended text & line in the update function like so

```
    tickPosNeg.select("line").transition().duration(600)
        .attr("x2",function(d, i){ if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] > 0)
{return -10;}else if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] < 0){return 10;}});

    tickPosNeg.select("text").transition().duration(600)
        .attr("x", function(d, i){ if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] > 0)
{return -25;}else if (data[i]['value' + TEAM] < 0){return 10;}});
```

If anyone has a better solution, feel free to still post your answer!

Here's the updated [**link**](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/e60c96349f811156de855fc9affc810c)